# After using require false in gems, do i have to load gem again and again wherever i need or it will be cached?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, rubygems

Due to slow server boot time issue I want to use require false with gems which I don't want to load during server start and then I will load them wherever I need those gems code. 
But  want to ask, gem will get load again and again in every file where I need them or load only once and then use it from cache (I have enabled cached).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `require` to not `load` to get the gems in you app and they'll be loaded only once.

See more: http://hiteshrawal.blogspot.com/2011/12/ruby-require-vs-load.html